# Query for select multiple values from 2 tables

Tags: php, sql, xml, ajax

Table names:

1. `tbla_can_types`

Fields are `fac_id,type_id,type_name,status`

1. `tbla_canteen_rates` (there is no data in this table)

Fields are `fac_id,cat_id,type_id,from time,to_time,rate,off_rate,status,effective_date.,can_id(sequence number)

```
<?php
include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
$conn=&ADONewconnection('oci8');
$conn->Pconnect('conn','hostname','username','pwd');
$fac_id=$_GET['fac_id'];
$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];
$file=fopen("text.txt","w+");
global $newId;
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>');
echo "<data>";
$ids = explode(",",$_POST["ids"]);

$rates="select type_id,from_time,to_time,rate,off_rate,status,to_char(effective_date,'dd-Mon-yyyy') e_date,can_id from tbla_canteen_rates where fac_id=$fac_id and cat_id=$cat_id order by to_number(substr(from_time,0,length(from_time)-3))";
    $rs1=$conn->Execute($rates);
    if(!$rs1->EOF)
    echo $rs1->fields[0].'~'.$rs1->fields[1].'~'.$rs1->fields[2].'~'.$rs1->fields[3].'~'.$rs1->fields[4].'~'.$rs1->fields[5].'~'.$rs1->fields[6].'~'.$rs1->fields[7];
    $temp_id=$rs1->fields[0];
    echo $temp_id;
    $rs1->MoveNext();

    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($ids); $i++)
    { 
        $rowId = $ids[$i]; //id or row which was updated 
        $newId = $rowId; //will be used for insert operation    
        $mode = $_POST[$rowId."_!nativeeditor_status"]; //get request mode
        switch($mode)
        {
        case "inserted":
          $insert= "insert into tbla_canteen_rates(type_id,from_time,to_time,rate,off_rate,status,effective_date,fac_id,cat_id )values
            ($temp_id,
             '".$_POST[$rowId."_c1"]."',
             '".$_POST[$rowId."_c2"]."',
             '".$_POST[$rowId."_c3"]."',
             '".$_POST[$rowId."_c4"]."',
             '".$_POST[$rowId."_c5"]."',to_date('".$_POST[$rowId."_c6"]."','dd-Mon-yyyy'),$fac_id,$cat_id)";
          $conn->Execute($insert);
          fwrite($file,$insert);
          $action='add_row($rowId)';
        break;
        case "deleted":
            $delete = "delete from tbla_canteen_rates where can_id=".$rowId ;
            $conn->Execute($delete);
            fwrite($file,$delete);
            $action ='delete_row($rowId)';
        break;
        default:
            $update ="update tbla_canteen_rates set 
                    type_id=$temp_id,
                    from_time='".$_POST[$rowId."_c1"]."',
                    to_time='".$_POST[$rowId."_c2"]."',
                    rate='".$_POST[$rowId."_c3"]."',
                    off_rate='".$_POST[$rowId."_c4"]."',
                    status='".$_POST[$rowId."_c5"]."',
                    effective_date=to_date('".$_POST[$rowId."_c6"]."','dd-Mon-yyyy'),
                    fac_id='$fac_id',cat_id='$cat_id'
                    where  can_id=".$rowId;
            $conn->Execute($update);
            fwrite($file,$update);
            $action = 'update_row($rowId)';
        break;
        }   
        echo "<action type='".$action."' sid='".$rowId."' tid='".$newId."'/>";
    }
    echo "</data>";
    ?>
```

In the query i need id for type_id in a variable
i have written but every time it is getting id of first element only.

in this i need an id for type_id.

please send me the code 4 that

Regards

Pawan

Comment: if you need null values for the fields where data is not present use left join.

Comment: @pawan is that what you wanted, to find the type_names not in tbla_canteen_rates? Because the answer I just posted joins those two together, where available, instead

Comment: This is a completely different question than before editing. Please post another question.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a sneaking suspicion that you've got several questions in there, but since you asked about the sql query, this should work:

Note: I'm assuming fac_id is the id that binds the two tables together. "var_fac_id" and "var_cat_id" are the values from your comboboxes.

```
Select t1.type_name, t2.from_time, t2.to_time, t2.rate
FROM tbla_can_types as t1 LEFT JOIN tbla_canteen_rates as t2
ON t1.fac_id = t2.fac_id
WHERE t1.fac_id = var_fac_id AND t2.cat_id = var_cat_id
```

Further notes: I think this should work despite the "AND t2.cat_id = var_cat_id" (which obviously would find not results in an empty table), since it's a left join. If it returns an empty set, however, see if it works if you remove it.

**Update:**
your comment above makes me think the tables are bound together by type_id instead. If that's the case, use `ON t1.type_id = t2.type_id` instead of `ON t1.fac_id = t2.fac_id`

**Update #2 based on poster's comments**
I'm not going to do your homework, dude. And homework is the only place where they'd tell you to not do joins. I will send you to some resources that will help you learn this stuff, though. Check out the basic mysql example from php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php . That sample actually gets you pretty close to what you need. Also their overall mysql documentation, which is good for looking up what specific functions do: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php . Finally, remember that you're learning two languages here -- PHP, along with its functions to access a mysql DB, and -- SQL, which is a query language used within DBs. For SQL, check out http://sqlzoo.net/ , which seems a decent introduction on how to write queries.

Good luck on your assignment.

Comment: We can also write "AND" instead of "WHERE" keyword. This query will be optimized. Because it will check left join for these 3 conditions. Time complexity will be an issue for large databases.

Comment: Don't forget to acknowledge it by accepting the answer if it has served the purpose.

Comment: @pawan If all you wanted was the type_names, you can simply do: SELECT type_name FROM tbla_can_types

Comment: @pawan that LEFT JOIN in my example will give you a result for every match in the left hand table (the first one), and add the data from the right hand table, if it has it. If that right hand table doesn't have data (as it doesn't, since that table is blank), it will still include that column in the result set, it will simply be blank -- which is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: ... Really? Let me quote you: "i want the select Query from the above two tables like the table structure look likes". That's what I gave you. If you want it "presented in the correct format", then ask for the "correct format". If, on the other hand, the query didn't give the right result set, then say that, say what it did return, and if it threw an error, say what the error was.

Comment: I updated my answer to give you one last bit of help -- though it's not the kind of help you're asking for. Say hi to your instructor for me.

Comment: so, why use that 'not in', then? Do you have to exclude types that exist in canteen_rates that have that fac_id and the selected cat_id? Cause that's what you're doing with that first query. On another thing - why are you concatenating fields into the values of $rates_arr, only to explode it back out into $final_arr? You can put an array into the value of an array element, you know. That's called a multidimensional array, and they're pretty sweet. You can ditch final_arr/explode entirely that way. Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php , particularly example #7

Comment: With the left join that you're doing in query #2, you will get back empty values for the right hand table, where it doesn't have a matching entry. Besides that, if you wanted to, you could load empty values into the array while you're looping through the result set. Now, where you say "so I could insert the values in those empty cells", if you're talking about being able to type into textboxes in the web page, and have it save to the database, that's a different story. For that, you've got to start with the html, and put some textboxes there in a form.

Comment: you'll have to read the dhtmlxgrid documentation to sort that out. I have no experience with it.

Comment: Instead of that concat with '~', and subsequent split (what happens if your data has a '~' in it, for instance??), simply echo the data in JSON format in your php file. check out http://www.json.org . I think you'll find the dhtmlxgrid will probably be easier to work with if you do that, too. Doing an AJAX call that loads JSON data is pretty standard, so I imagine it has the ability to do that built in.

Comment: Also, dude, don't put your connect strings out on the internet - $conn->Pconnect('10.1.17.8:1521','eaccess','eaccess','tandev');. That is a huge security risk. I'll grant that IP is a local intranet IP, but that still means anyone at your college can get in your DB and mess with it. When you copy/paste code, change it to look something like this: $conn->Pconnect('hostname','dbname','username','password');

Comment: Oh, and for outputting JSON, check out the function json_encode on php.net. You can use that to echo out your array in json format in one line. And it can handle multidimensional arrays, so for the love of donuts, stop with the '~' concat.

Comment: The same way you're doing any of the other queries.

Comment: That's why you loop through your results. 'while', not 'if'

Comment: $rates="select type_id,from_time,to_time,rate,off_rate,status,to_char(effective_date,'dd-Mon-yyyy') e_date,can_id from tbla_canteen_rates where fac_id=$fac_id and cat_id=$cat_id order by to_number(substr(from_time,0,length(from_time)-3))";
$rs1=$conn->Execute($rates);
while(!$rs1->EOF)
{
echo $rs1->fields[0].'~'.$rs1->fields[1].'~'.$rs1->fields[2].'~'.$rs1->fields[3].'~'.$rs1->fields[4].'~'.$rs1->fields[5].'~'.$rs1->fields[6].'~'.$rs1->fields[7];
$temp_id=$rs1->fields[0];
$rs1->MoveNext();
echo $temp_id;
} in $temp_id ill get id for type_id but when im using this in insert stmnt.

Comment: but im not getting the id for temp_id.

Comment: $insert= "insert into tbla_canteen_rates(type_id,from_time,to_time,rate,off_rate,status,effective_date,fac_id,cat_id )values
  ('".$temp_id."',
   '".$_POST[$rowId."_c1"]."',
   '".$_POST[$rowId."_c2"]."',
   '".$_POST[$rowId."_c3"]."',
   '".$_POST[$rowId."_c4"]."',
   '".$_POST[$rowId."_c5"]."',to_date('".$_POST[$rowId."_c6"]."','dd-Mon-yyyy'),$fac_id,$cat_id)";
   $conn->Execute($insert);//im not getting the id over there

Comment: Right. You're doing the first query when you generate the page. You're doing the second query after the page has posted back to the server on submit. The second query has no knowledge of $temp_id. It doesn't exist in that context. Further, even if it did, in that while loop, you keep overwriting $temp_id, so even if it did know it, it would only have the last type_id read from the server. You want to post back the type_id along with all the other variables. That means either putting it into a textbox like the others, or into hidden variables. (look up html's input type hidden)

Comment: did you even do what I said, and look up input type hidden?

Comment: $typ_id="select type_id from tbla_can_types where fac_id=$fac_id and type_name='$type_name'";
 $rs2=$conn->Execute($typ_id);
 $type_id=$rs2->fields[0];//type_id,                        i have taken the typename in variable and assigned to it.

Comment: select e1.type_name,e2.from_time,e2.to_time,e2.rate,e2.off_rate,e2.status,to_char(e2.effective_date,'dd-Mon-yyyy') from tbla_can_types e1 LEFT JOIN tbla_canteen_rates e2 ON e1.type_id=e2.type_id where e1.fac_id=1 order by e1.type_id

Comment: if i use left join im getting it but when i enter records it will reflect on every cat_id of type_name(suppose cat_id=12 it has 4 type_id's (say breakfast,lunch,buffet,dinner) if i insert type_name(BREAK FST) it is inserted on every change of cat_id and its corresponding type_id and fac_id.

Comment: becoz even in where condition i have to take cat_id if i do so it will return only one row of type_id.,every time the page loads it has to show all the typenames.and rest of the cells empty.

Comment: If you need a list of type_ids where each type_id is only listed once, and you're pulling from a table where any given type_id can be listed multiple times, you can use the sql keyword 'DISTINCT'. So, "SELECT DISTINCT type_id FROM ..."

Comment: i have exploded the types and placed inthe first cell and in the else part i have given empty cells.,in this loop it will show if data exists in tbla_can_rates else it prints empty.this way i got it.

Comment: hi patches can u tell me how to do the time validation.

Comment: what, exactly do you mean by time validation?